# Cron Expression syntax required

Tags: cronexpression

I want a cron expression which should run every minute between 1pm to 1.30pm everyday.

Can anyone provide me with the syntax.

24 0/1 13-13:30 ? * * somehow doesn't work. Is it possible to include such range in cron.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
0-30 13 * * * /my/command
```

The first field specifies the minutes (a range from 0 to 30, inclusive). The second is the hour. The remainder specify the day of month, month and day of week.

See [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) for more info and some caveats re. what's supported

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for your reply,
 
In case I require this from 1pm to 2.30 pm to run every minute in this interval then how can this syntax be modified.

Is this possible ?

Comment: I suspect you may need two expressions - one for 1pm to 2pm, and one for 2pm to 230pm

Comment: Yes, It seems so,

Tested few cases but nothing suffice. Anyways thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

use this expression-
0 0-30 13 * * ?

Comment: if u want to write expression for 1 PM to 2:30 PM everyday then use this expression- 0 0-30 13,14 * * ?